# PAYPAL is giving error "DPRP is disabled"

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am implementing paypal using PHP. It is working fine in SANBOX mode.

But, when i am implementing it to LIVE it is giving error "DPRP is disabled".

Is Paypal Direct Payment API Component class file (API51.0) requires paypal business pro 2.0 or 3.0 ?

So how to fix it please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

THe DPRP error revolves around the recurring payments to be enabled on the account. If you are integrating classic APIs with recurring payments(user,pw,sig), then you'll have to sign up for it, but you'll have to call paypal and request it.

If you have a pro 2.0 account, then you'll want to sign up for recurring billing ($10 a mos), this will resolve your issue